# MySQL: check whether two fields on a model are always the same?

Tags: mysql

I'm a total database newbie and I'm probably using the wrong terminology to search for answers.

I have a MySQL table as follows:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| placeid    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| grid       | varchar(120)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vill       | varchar(300)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'd like to find out whether 'grid' and 'vill' always occur in the same combinations or not.

Maybe it'd be clearer with an example:

```
placeid, grid, vill
1,       TM1,  Suffolk
2,       TM1,  Suffolk
3,       WA8,  Newcastle
4,       WA8,  Newcastle
5,       WA8,  York
```

I'd like to construct a query that returns 'WA8' but not 'TM1', because 'WA8' occurs in combination with more than one vill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT grid
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY grid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT vill) > 1
```

It selects the grids for which there is more than one distinct vill.

Comment: How would it go if there were 10, 20 fields in table and each one could have duplicate values? Not that it's realistic scenario, but in theory?

Comment: You mean COUNT(DISTINCT vill1, vill2, vill3...) > 1?